# what is the hostname (FDN0 or IP address of the server that ubuntu Whoopise and apport use?

Tags: networking

what is the hostname (FDN) or IP address of the server that Ubuntu's whoopise and apport use?

I have a very restricted firewall rules in Ubuntu 20.x and want to make sure I open a path for this error reporting end point.

PS, was not able to find it through google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  don't know the port that it uses, but I know the website and IP address it sends the bug reports to. It sends them to https://daisy.ubuntu.com which is [162.213.33.132](https://162.213.33.132) .